# Installing Compass on Windows - fail - can't find dependency ffi

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cygwin, compass

I run cygwin-64 bits on Windows 7. I have installed Ruby2.3 64 bit and Ruby DevKit.

I try to install Compass using ruby gems. I get this:

```
$gem install compass
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.10
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
        rb-inotify requires ffi (>= 0.5.0)
```

This is the verbose version:

```
    $ gem install compass --verbose
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=compass
200 OK
Getting SRV record failed: DNS result has no information for _rubygems._tcp.api.rubygems.org
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=chunky_png,compass-core,compass-import-once,rb-fsevent,rb-inotify,sass
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=ffi,multi_json
200 OK
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/COPYING
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/LICENSE
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/README.md
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/Rakefile
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/AbstractMemory.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/AbstractMemory.h
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/ArrayType.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/ArrayType.h
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/Buffer.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/Call.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/Call.h
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/ClosurePool.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/ClosurePool.h
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/DataConverter.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/DynamicLibrary.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/DynamicLibrary.h
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/Function.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/Function.h
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/FunctionInfo.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/LastError.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/LastError.h
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/LongDouble.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/LongDouble.h
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/MappedType.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/MappedType.h
...
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/struct.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/struct_layout_builder.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/tools/const_generator.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/tools/generator.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/tools/generator_task.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/tools/struct_generator.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/tools/types_generator.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/types.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/union.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/variadic.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/version.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/Benchmark.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/BoolTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/BufferTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/ClosureTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/EnumTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/FunctionTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/GNUmakefile
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/GlobalVariable.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/LastErrorTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/NumberTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/PointerTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/ReferenceTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/StringTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/StructTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/UnionTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/libtest/VariadicTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/LICENSE.SPECS
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/async_callback_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/bool_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/buffer_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/callback_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/custom_param_type.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/custom_type_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/dup_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/enum_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/errno_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/ffi_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/Benchmark.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/BoolTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/BufferTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/ClosureTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/EnumTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/FunctionTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/GNUmakefile
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/GlobalVariable.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/LastErrorTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/NumberTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/PointerTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/ReferenceTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/StringTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/StructTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/UnionTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/VariadicTest.c
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/fixtures/classes.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/function_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/io_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/library_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/long_double.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/managed_struct_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/memorypointer_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/number_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/platform_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/pointer_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/rbx/attach_function_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/rbx/memory_pointer_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/rbx/spec_helper.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/rbx/struct_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/spec_helper.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/string_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/strptr_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/struct_by_ref_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/struct_callback_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/struct_initialize_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/struct_packed_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/struct_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/typedef_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/union_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/ffi/variadic_spec.rb
C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/spec/spec.opts
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
current directory: /home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160419-7812-1d7ip8w.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi_call() in -lffi... yes
checking for ffi_prep_closure()... yes
checking for ffi_raw_call()... yes
checking for ffi_prep_raw_closure()... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile
current directory: /home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR=" clean
rm -f
rm -f ffi_c.so  *.o  *.bak mkmf.log .*.time
current directory: /home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR="
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o AbstractMemory.o -c AbstractMemory.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o ArrayType.o -c ArrayType.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o Buffer.o -c Buffer.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o Call.o -c Call.c
In file included from Call.c:62:0:
Call.c: In function ‘do_blocking_call’:
Thread.h:78:39: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rb_thread_call_without_gvl’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 # define rbffi_thread_blocking_region rb_thread_call_without_gvl
                                       ^
Call.c:368:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘rbffi_thread_blocking_region’
     rbffi_thread_blocking_region(call_blocking_function, data, (void *) -1, NULL);
     ^
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o ClosurePool.o -c ClosurePool.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o DataConverter.o -c DataConverter.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o DynamicLibrary.o -c DynamicLibrary.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o ffi.o -c ffi.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o Function.o -c Function.c
Function.c: In function ‘async_cb_event’:
Function.c:563:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rb_thread_call_without_gvl’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         rb_thread_call_without_gvl(async_cb_wait, &w, async_cb_stop, &w);
         ^
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o FunctionInfo.o -c FunctionInfo.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o LastError.o -c LastError.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o LongDouble.o -c LongDouble.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o MappedType.o -c MappedType.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o MemoryPointer.o -c MemoryPointer.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o MethodHandle.o -c MethodHandle.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o Platform.o -c Platform.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o Pointer.o -c Pointer.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o Struct.o -c Struct.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o StructByReference.o -c StructByReference.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o StructByValue.o -c StructByValue.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o StructLayout.o -c StructLayout.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o Thread.o -c Thread.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o Type.o -c Type.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o Types.o -c Types.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I.  -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration     -o Variadic.o -c Variadic.c
rm -f ffi_c.so
gcc -shared -o ffi_c.so AbstractMemory.o ArrayType.o Buffer.o Call.o ClosurePool.o DataConverter.o DynamicLibrary.o ffi.o Function.o FunctionInfo.o LastError.o LongDouble.o MappedType.o MemoryPointer.o MethodHandle.o Platform.o Pointer.o Struct.o StructByReference.o StructByValue.o StructLayout.o Thread.o Type.o Types.o Variadic.o -L. -L/usr/lib -L. -fstack-protector  -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import    -lruby220 -lffi  -lffi -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt
current directory: /home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR=" install
/usr/bin/mkdir -p . ./.gem.20160419-7812-9fvqix
exit > .RUBYARCHDIR.time
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 ffi_c.so ./.gem.20160419-7812-9fvqix
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/cygwin64/home/vsxxame/.gem/ruby/gems/extensions/x86_64-cygwin/ffi-1.9.10/mkmf.log
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.10
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
        rb-inotify requires ffi (>= 0.5.0)
```

I get the same if I try to install rb-inotify. Other gems are installed ok, . Any hints?